# Bash: Compound grep in

Tags: bash, if-statement, grep

Assume a file $tmpdir$results_tmp containing:

```
==========================
UNIT 1 OK
UNIT 2 OK
UNIT 3 OK
UNIT 4 OK
```

I want to conditionally grep the lines that begin with a digit, then grep those for "OK". If any of the lines that begin with a digit don't contain "OK", throw an error.

```
while read -r line
do
        if [ grep '^[0-9]' | grep -qv "OK" ]  <<< "$line"; then
                printf "$line"
                results=$results"BAD UNIT DETECTED: $line\n\n"
                PASS=false
        fi
done < $tmpdir$results_tmp
```

My assumption is that the first grep pulls out the lines that begin with a digit and the second grep evaluates those to see if they contain "OK", but that doesn't seem to be what's happening.

Can anyone see where I've made my misstep?e

Comment: None of the lines in your sample input "begin with a digit" which seems inconsistent with what your code is looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have four solutions here, two using `awk`, one using `sed`, and one using a slightly modified version of your bash code.

First, an `awk` solution:

```
awk '!/^[0-9]/ {next} !/OK/ {print "BAD UNIT DETECTED:",$0}' input
```

I tried this using sample input:

```
$ cat input
======
1 OK
2 not
text only
3 OK
4 OK
5 no status
```

And, the result is:

```
$ awk '!/^[0-9]/ {next} !/OK/ {print "BAD UNIT DETECTED:",$0}' input
BAD UNIT DETECTED: 2 not
BAD UNIT DETECTED: 5 no status
```

#### How it works

There are two `awk` commands.  The first is `!/^[0-9]/ {next}`.  This looks for any line that does not start with a digit (the exclamation point mean "not") and skips it.  The second is `!/OK/ {print "BAD UNIT DETECTED:",$0}`.  This looks any of the remaining lines that do not contain "OK" and prints them with an error message.

#### Alternate solution with `awk`

In the comments, JS points out that the logic can be reordered:

```
awk '/^[0-9]/ && !/OK/ {print "BAD UNIT DETECTED:",$0}' input
```

This looks for all lines which (a) do not begin with a digit, `/^[0-9]/`, and also (b) do not contain OK, `!/OK/`.  The `&&` is the `awk` notation for logical-and.  Any line passing both those tests is printed with the error message.

#### Alternate solution using `sed`

```
$ sed '/^[^0-9]/d; /OK/d; s/^/BAD UNIT DETECTED: /' input
BAD UNIT DETECTED: 2 not
BAD UNIT DETECTED: 5 no status
```

There are three `sed` commands here.  The first `/^[^0-9]/d` skips over any lines not beginning with a digit.  The next `/OK/d` slips over any of the remaining lines that have "OK" in them.  For any line that is left, an error message is prepended and it is printed.

#### Additional notes

A problem with your code is here:

```
[ grep '^[0-9]' | grep -qv "OK" ]  <<< "$line"
```

The leading `[` signals the start of a `test` command but what follows is not a valid test.  Since `grep` sets proper exit codes, a `test` command is not needed anyway.   The above probably should be replaced with:

```
grep '^[0-9]' <<<"$line" | grep -qv "OK"
```

or,

```
echo "$line | grep '^[0-9]' | grep -qv "OK"
```

A minimally-modified working version of your bash code is:

```
while read -r line
do
    if grep '^[0-9]' <<<"$line" | grep -qv "OK"
    then
        printf "$line\n"
        results="${results}BAD UNIT DETECTED: $line\n\n"
        PASS=false
    fi
done <input
```

Note that the `results` variable contains literal characters backslash and n.  This may or may not be what you want.

Comment: +1 for the explanation. The `awk` version can be written as `awk '/^[0-9]/&&!/OK/{print "BAD UNIT DETECTED:",$0}' input`

Comment: @JS웃 Thanks.  I just added your suggestion to the answer.

Comment: John1024, your bash answer is perfect. I apologise for the sloppy example: I transposed columns 1 & 2 so in fact, there are numbers at the start of every line except the line of ===. I went with your suggestion `if grep '^[0-9]' <<<"$line" | grep -qv "OK"`. I understand the test metaphor - a huge help in my understanding of bash scripting. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To complete John1024's answer (which is already complete) : the double bracket syntax of Bash provide the operator `=~` which allows us to use regular expressions.

So, when you write bash scripts,  it's generally not useful to use external commands like `grep` or `expr` in your blocks (`if`, `while`, ...).

For example, you could use :

```
while read -r; do
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[0-9] && ! $REPLY =~ OK ]]; then
        # ...
    fi 
done < file
```

Instead of :

```
while read -r line; do
    if grep '^[0-9]' <<<"$line" | grep -qv "OK"; then
        # ...
    fi
done < file
```

On the other hand, the `^[0-9]` pattern match only if the line begin whith a numeric character. 
This never seems to be the case according to your input sample.

Comment: Idriss Neumann, Always good to have another idiom available! Cheers!

Comment: @user2510065 I'm glad to help you. I hope you understand the value of avoid multiple external commands in your scripts when it's possible.